# Program type already present: com.paytm.pg.AppTest

Tags: android, gradle

I have 2 binary libraries my app depends on, A and B. They both happen to declare a common class CTest, that results in an the titular error. Is there any way for me to resolve this? I have gone through a lot of problems listed here with the same title but most of them simply offer options like delete one dependency, which is not an option for me.

Thank you for any response in advance

Comment: Hi, Did You solve the issue ? Could You please post Your Code and some hint?

Comment: facing same issue, any breakthrough in this?

Comment: I never managed to solve this, but the thing is that PayTM was never designed to be used in this way. You need to set up a server and have it do the checking. If you don't care about that, and just want a demo payment thing, then you should use some other payment service, like PayU or PhonePe.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are doing paytm payment integration, if so you can remove the Checksum Jar. You do not have to use the jar in case of Android. Use the gradle dependency only (com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.3.3') and then check.

Comment: Hi, I had faced the same problem. But, Once I remove .jar file, I don't get the CheckSumHelper.java file. Can You tell me how to get the CheckSumHelper.java file and generate the CheckSum ?

Comment: Yes, Sourav. same issues I am facing. have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

without .jar CheckSumServiceHelper is not import

```java
CheckSumServiceHelper.getCheckSumServiceHelper().genrateCheckSum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following link to check for dependency for the platform you use : 
[maven link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paytm/pgplussdk/1.3.3)

Moreover this issue occurs when u trying to use jar made for a java application in android. I understand normally we ahould be able to use that, but somehow in case we can not use PaytmChecksum.jar in android. Probably it was never tested and made for this. You need to create a java application and than use that jar in that.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue what I was doing was I downloaded the jar file from here..

[Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_Java](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_Java)

But if you are doing it for the android app you are supposed to use this

[Paytm_Google_App_Engine_Kit](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Google_App_Engine_Kit)

So just remove the old jar file downloaded from the previous link and replace it with google app engine jar file

> Note: you are supposed to generate the checksum string like this

```
TreeMap<String,String> parameters = new TreeMap<String,String>();
String merchantKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //Key provided by Paytm
parameters.put("MID", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); // Merchant ID (MID) provided by Paytm
parameters.put("ORDER_ID", "nnnnnnnnn"); // Merchant’s order id
parameters.put("CUST_ID", "CUST001"); // Customer ID registered with merchant
parameters.put("TXN_AMOUNT", "1");
parameters.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WEB");
parameters.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail"); //Provided by Paytm
parameters.put("WEBSITE", "xxxxxxxxxxx"); //Provided by Paytm
//Note: Above mentioned parameters are not complete list of parameters. Please refer integration document for additional parameters which need to be passed.
String checkSum = checkSumServiceHelper.genrateCheckSumGAE(merchantKey, parameters);
```

> Although it fixed the error but you still need to create checksum from
>   the server i.e you are not supposed to put this inside the app